# Incorrect NDVI range results in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, ndvi, orthophoto

I am creating NDVI from multispectral orthoimagery for multiple years. For the majority of the data, results from NDVI using the Image Analysis window range between -1 and 1 as expected.
However for the most recent year in the data, all of the NDVI values range from -1 less than 1 (0.56, 0.64, etc...). All of the attributes of the data seem to be identical to the previous years.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Often one needs to run satellite data through the calculate statistics tool to ensure up to date stats in the aux file to visualise full range of values. Try that?